# SonarQube Scanner for jenkins doesn't scan test coverage and also doesn't map variables from Maven

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, gitlab, sonarqube-scan

I have configured Jenkins job that is analyzing projects from GitLab. It's working properly, however, it's for some reason always showing up test coverage of given repos to be 0%, which is not true(I know there is a question answered about this on stack but i don't think it¨s really up to date).

The other thing is that I need to have mapped projectKey so it would use artifactID from pom.xml file, I cannot have it hardcoded because the job is analyzing many projects after being triggered by webhooks from GitLab and they must have they specific names given.

When I try to use current config and I use mapped value for projectKey, this is the job's console output:

```
Validation of project reactor failed:
  o "" is not a valid project or module key. Allowed characters are alphanumeric, '-', '_', '.' and ':', with at least one non-digit.
```

I suppose it means the value is empty so it's not maping any value.

Those are images of my job config, thank you.

[config part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl0mj.png) [config part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfiCI.png) [config part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boFGL.png)

My jacoco maven plugin configuration inside pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
    </dependency>


         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Did you configure the maven jacoco plugin for the coverage?

Comment: @Ivthillo Well, I have it in my pom.xml file in the projects I'm up to analyze. When I was trying to analyze projects directly from terminal inside IDE, it worked even with test coverage results. When I configured this jenkins job, it's not showing coverages. About Jacoco I have one dependency and one plugin in there, I'm posting my exact config to original post.